# requests_html + Django "There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'."

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-requests-html

Good, I have in Django this configuration in urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

and in views.py the index function where I pass through the variable a url, I have with requests_html:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from .main import *

def index(request):
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    # URLValidator...
    session = HTMLSession()
    resp = session.get(url)
    resp.html.render()
```

```
resp.html.render()
  File "/home/noname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "/home/noname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 727, in browser
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

But I get a bug when calling render() and I'm not using threads, any ideas?

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Show us your imports too (what is `HTMLSession`? - I don't think that is from django..?)

Comment: The current error message might be more informative "Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead." (from https://github.com/psf/requests-html/blob/026c4e5217cfc8347614148aab331d81402f596b/requests_html.py#L797)

Comment: If you're running `manage.py runserver` then it is multithreaded by default. You might get around it by using `--nothreading` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver)

Comment: with --nothreading obtain "There is no current event loop in thread 'django-main-thread'" ...

Comment: With AsyncHTMLSession obtain the same ... :(

Comment: having the same issue...have you ever solved this?? @Javi